# Grep not understanding whitespace delimiter?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

In the following example:

```
apt-file search apache2.conf | grep -E "apache2.conf\b"
```

Output:

```
apache2: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
apache2-doc: /usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/apache2.conf.gz
dicoweb: /etc/dicoweb/apache2.conf
emboss-explorer: /etc/apache2/conf-available/emboss-explorer.apache2.conf
emboss-explorer: /etc/emboss-explorer/apache2.conf
icinga-cgi: /usr/share/doc/icinga-cgi/examples/apache2.conf
icinga-cgi: /usr/share/icinga/apache2.conf
icinga2-classicui: /etc/icinga2-classicui/apache2.conf
kopano-webapp-apache2: /etc/apache2/conf-available/kopano-webapp-apache2.conf
kopano-webapp-apache2: /etc/kopano/webapp/apache2.conf
lacme: /etc/lacme/apache2.conf
lemonldap-ng-handler: /etc/apache2/sites-available/handler-apache2.conf
libjs-twitter-bootstrap: /usr/share/twitter-bootstrap/apache2.conf
liblemonldap-ng-manager-perl: /etc/apache2/sites-available/manager-apache2.conf
liblemonldap-ng-portal-perl: /etc/apache2/sites-available/portal-apache2.conf
mirmon: /usr/share/doc/mirmon/examples/mirror-apache2.conf
nagios3-cgi: /usr/share/nagios3-cgi/apache2.conf
oar-restful-api: /usr/share/oar/oar-api/apache2.conf
octopussy: /etc/octopussy/apache2.conf
spip: /usr/share/doc/spip/apache2.conf
```

Why doesn't `grep` understand the `\b` as word boundary and incorporates this line:

```
apache2-doc: /usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/examples/apache2/apache2.conf.gz
```

Same result occurs with and without the usage of the extended (`-E`) version of `grep`.

Comment: use the `-P` instead of the `-E` option; `\b` is a perl/pcre thing.

Comment: thanks. the fact that `\b` works with `-E` version of `sed` confused me tbh; what is the word boundary equivalent for `-E` then?

Comment: `\<` and `\>` should work in `grep` either with `-E` or with old-style regexps.

Comment: However it seems that the `-P` flag also retrievs the above line ...

Comment: because it matches it; `conf` is at the end of the word in `apache2.conf.gz`.

Comment: try with `grep -P 'apache2\.conf(?=\s|$)'` if you want `conf` to only match before a whitespace or at the end of the line.

Comment: thx the last recommendation did the job;

Comment: @mosvy GNU `grep` understands `\b` just fine. Try `printf "1aa(bb\n2aabb\n" | grep 'aa\b'`.

Comment: even better and more idiomatic would be `grep -P 'apache2\.conf(?!\S)'` using a zero-width negative look-ahead assertion -- meaning "`conf` not followed by a non-space".

Answer (score 6):

A *word boundary* is a transition from a word character to a non-word character - that's not the same as a transition from a word character to whitespace.

From `man grep`:

> Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the underscore.

Since `.` is a non-word character `conf\b` matches "`conf` followed by `.`".

Answer (score 2):

[@steeldriver already explained what `\b` is about](/a/513575), I'll just add that `apt-file search` supports extended regexp by itself with the `-x` option, and that you can look for paths *ending* in `apache2.conf` with:

```
apt-file search -x 'apache2\.conf$'
```

You could also do:

```
apt-file search -x 'apache2\.conf(\s|$)'
```

To look for paths that end in `apache2.conf` or contain `apache2.conf` followed by whitespace, but I doubt it will make any difference as I don't expect any file in the `apt-file` database contains `apache2.conf<whitespace>`.